# Get First element by the recent date of each group

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have following model in django

```
Business ID
Business Name
Business Revenue
Date
```

Here is the sample data:

```
Business ID | Business Name | Business Revenue | Date
1             B1              1000               2012-10-13
2             B2              20000              2013-10-16
1             B1              2000               2013-04-13
2             B2              24000              2014-09-02
```

I want to fetch all businesses having latest date.

Here is the output I want:

```
Business ID | Business Name | Business Revenue | Date
1             B1              2000               2013-04-13
2             B2              24000              2014-09-02
```

I have tried this:

```
model.objects.filter(date__gte = date.today()).order_by('business_id', '-date')
```

This is giving me group of businesses having latest business in each group at the top of it. How do I omit the rest of rows? I need some assistance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

group_dict = Model.objects.values('business_id').annotate(max_date=Max('date')).order_by()

params = Q()
for obj in group_dict:
    params |= (Q(business_id__exact=obj['business_id']) & Q(date=obj['max_date']))

qs = Model.objects.filter(params)
```

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) can help u.

> If the values() clause precedes the annotate() clause, any annotations
>   will be automatically added to the result set. However, if the
>   values() clause is applied after the annotate() clause, you need to
>   explicitly include the aggregate column.

Comment: I have already tried this approach but I also want the values of other columns like Business_Name, Revenue

Comment: It worked, however, it requires indexing for the larger data set. Thank you

Comment: It is very slow for large tables

Answer (score 11):

If you are using PostgreSQL  [[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct), you can use `order_by()` and `distinct()` methods:

```py
Model.objects.all().order_by('business_id', '-date').distinct('business_id')
```