# Get last Django db model instance created corresponding to conditional field filter?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I've this Django database model:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    relevant_field = IntergerField()
    ...
```

Instances are created with different values for `relevant_field`, let's say `1`, `2`, `3`, `1`, `2`, `3`. Now I'd like to get the single latest (created most recently) instance for every field value `1`, `2` and `3`. How do I have to implement the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241872/get-first-element-by-the-recent-date-of-each-group

Comment: I don't think so. The question referenced uses an explicit `date` field which is used to determine "latest".

Comment: You can use the `id` field instead.

Comment: In this case I'll give it a try. Thx

Comment: What would I have to do in case the `relevant_field` is not of the model itself but a one-to-one referenced model? `Something` references `SomethingReferenced` which has field `relevant_field`? First I thought I could split the problem up and solve via devide and conquer. However it's possible to ask w.r.t. the overall question right away...?

Comment: As stated in the accepted answer of referenced question, instead of `Model.objects.values('business_id')` you should do `Model.objects.values('somethingrefer__relevant_field')`

Comment: Thx. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @nima No, the solution cannot be applied cause the dict is not constructed with consideration of the "latest" id.

Comment: If you sort records by `-id` you will get them by "latest" as you want.